# get chart value in point

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

For example I have chart with 2 points - 0,0 and 10,10 and chart type is FastLine.
I want to know what Y value will be in chart in choosen X value.

For example when X is 5 I want to know that Y is 5.

My charts more complicated and have tons of points, I need to get Y value through X.

How can I do this?

Comment: This is not really possible unless you actually have one or more points at the given x-value. All you can do is try to interpolate the y-value by simple math. Note that line charts allow you to move to and fro with the lines so any x-value can have many y-values and a line through it may cross many of the chart lines. - For the interpolation you need to find the two neighbouring points and work with them. The math is really trivial.

Comment: I thought if line was already calculated and drawn I can get value of Y on X even without a point there. I want to get Y value of each series on certain X to summarize them later and create 1 chart, like total balance.

Comment: Yes, if it really is just a line and not a curve you can calculate any point on it, as I said. But this means that you need to know the endpoints of that line. From there it is simple and if you know that the x-vlues will always move forward this is not hard at all..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem boils down to two tasks:

- Finding the neighbouring points for an x-value
- Interpolating their y-values for the given x-value.

If the x-values are indeed steadily increasing this should solve both:

```
double interpolatedY(Series s, double xval)
{
    DataPoint pPrev = s.Points.Last(x => x.XValue <= xval);
    DataPoint pNext = s.Points.First(x => x.XValue >= xval);

    if (pPrev == pNext) return pPrev.YValues[0];

    return pPrev.YValues[0] + (pNext.YValues[0] - pPrev.YValues[0])
        * (xval  - pPrev.XValue)/ (pNext.XValue - pPrev.XValue); 
}
```

It uses Linq to find the previous and next datapoint and then uses simple math to find the interpolated value.

Note that most checks are omitted!

Here I have added an identical point series and a third one to add the interpolated values:

[image]

To convert between chart pixels and values there are `Axis` functions `ValueToPixelPosition` and `PixelPositionToValue`, btw.